# Error message displayed when open recorded test plan

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Error message:"Error in Testplan-See log file".
How can i fix this and open relevant test plan?Appreciate if someone can give me a solution for this.

Comment: Add here at least that message from log file, maybe there's some clue.

Comment: I have recorded a script for wiki page. It’s worked fine many times. But now that test plan is unable to open. When i trying to open the test plan, an error message displayed in jmeter. Error message:Error in Test plan-See log files. How can i recover that test plan?

Comment: Well, see log files then. It should be located in jmeter folder and called jmeter.log. There you will find information what went wrong. That can help.